# Passing grid panel data via request payload to REST controller

Tags: rest, extjs, controller, request, payload

I have a user form that is created in extjs framework. The user form has many user fields which are being passed as part of request payload to the REST controller.
I am trying to add a grid panel(most likely in a tabular format with multiple rows & columns) to the user form. 
But I am not sure how to pass the grid panel data as part of request payload to the REST controller. 
I will post more code if any more details are needed. 
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

```
Ext.define('soylentgreen.view.admin.UserForm', {
    extend : 'Ext.form.Panel',
    alias : 'widget.userform',
    bodyStyle : 'padding:5px 5px 0',

// some userform elements like firstname,lastname, go here.....

name : 'userTeamGrid',
  xtype : 'gridpanel',
id : 'userTeamGrid',
itemId : 'userTeamGrid',
multiSelect : true,
selModel : Ext.create(
        'Ext.selection.CheckboxModel',
        {
          injectCheckbox : 'first',
          mode : 'MULTI',
          checkOnly : false
        }),
anchor : '100%',
width : '700px',
height : 250,
flex : 1,
store : 'userTeamStore',

var user = form.getRecord();
form.updateRecord(user);
user.save({
        callback : function(records, operation){
          //reset the (static) proxy extraParams object
          user.getProxy().extraParams =  {
            requestType: 'standard'
          }
          if(!operation.wasSuccessful()){
            var error = operation.getError();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMO, That's one of the most complicated yet common issues we face in ExtJS. It has to be solved often, but most solutions have to be slightly different depending on the exact requirements.

Grids are bound to a full store, not to a single record. So if you want to get data from a record (e.g. as an array) into a grid and vice versa, you have to have a mapping between the data from the store and the value in a single field of a record. To e.g. get all data from the store, the generic solution is

```
store.getRange().map(function(record) { return record.getData(); });
```

If you need only the grid selection (maybe you want to use a `checkboxselection` model or similar) and/or only certain fields of the records, you have to change this code to your needs, e.g.

```
grid.getSelectionModel().getSelection().map(function(record) {return record.get('Id'); });
```

So, your record is bound to the form, and a form consists of fields. How do you get the grid data to be accepted as part of the form?

You have to add a `hiddenfield` to your form and, depending on your requirement, overwrite some of the four functions `setValue`, `getValue`, `getModelData`, `getSubmitValue`. Usually, the `hiddenfield` tries to convert its value to a string, but obviously, you need to allow for arrays there; and you want to modify the grid whenever `setValue` is called, or read the value from the grid whenever one of the getters is called. The four functions are used for the following:

- `setValue` should be used to modify the grid based on the value you find in the record.
- `getValue` is used in comparison operations (check whether the value has changed, which means the form is dirty and has to be submitted, etc.) and if you call `form.getValues`. You should return some value based on the grid state in it.
- `getModelData` is used by the `form.updateRecord` method; it should return a value that the model field's convert method can work with.
- `getSubmitValue` is used by the `form.submit` method, it should return a value that can be safely transmitted to the server (has to be a string if the form doesn't have `sendAsJson:true` set)

I cannot give you an exact recipe for these implementations, as they are specific to your requirements.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response. I am trying to code in the way you explained. 
I created a xtype as hiddenfield for arrays to be bound in user form, 
when I'm calling setValue in the hidden field whenever the grid data is changed, 
it's data is saved as [object, Object] instead of an array value. 
Can you tell me how to store that data as exact array in hiddenfield?

Comment: @PoonkodiSivapragasam As I said, you have to override the setValue function so that it accepts arrays.

Comment: After I tried to override, I'm getting below error ext-all.js:15 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '$className' of undefined
    at Object.override (ext-all.js:15) . Can you tell me what's wrong with my code ?   Ext.override('Ext.form.field.Hidden', {
      setValue: function(val) {
          this.callParent(['In override']);
          return this;
      }
  });